# How to make GPS function work?

Tags: android, eclipse, gps

I'm new at Eclipse and the Android applications making so here comes a very rookie question. How can I make this function work properly? I have just copy > paste it to my `public class nowActivity extends Activity {` and fixed the errors that accord. The function is as follows:

```
package weather.right;

import weather.right.now.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class nowActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
             Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    }

    public void goToSo(View view) {
        goToUrl("http://erik-edgren.nu/weather");
    }

    private void goToUrl(String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

        private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
             .setCancelable(false)
             .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                          Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                  }
             });
             alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                       dialog.cancel();
                  }
             });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState)` should be `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`?

You are supposed to override the `onCreate()` method. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) for more details.

For Android, sub-classes of `Activity` are supposed to implement certain methods so to do this you have to override certain methods by matching the parent class' methods exactly. `onCreate()` is one such method.

For the emulator, GPS can be tested by following the guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html). Otherwise it will show up as disabled.

Comment: Um. Yes? That's the second line in that code. What's your point? I'm new within these "walls", remember.

Comment: @ErikEdgren It should be `onCreate()`, not `onCreate1()` (note the trailing `1`). However, if you're actually aiming to declare a method with the trailing `1`, then disregard the response above. onCreate() would however be called automatically as it's a vital method for all Activies in Android. :)

Comment: Thanks but nothing happens once again :( I'm testing my application trough Android Virtual Device in Eclipse. That maybe is the problem? If not, how can I fix this? :)

Comment: @ninetwozero I got the "duplicated" error message when I tried to use `onCreate()`. I removed `onCreate1()` and moved it's content to `onCreate()`. Same thing there - nothing happens.

Comment: @ErikEdgren: That's odd, do you have the appropriate permissions set in AndroidManifest.xml? Also, could you copy&paste the exact error message into your original post?

Comment: @ninetwozero I got this in AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` under `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`. I don't have any error messages right now but I had when I had duplicated `onCreate()`. The error message then was "Duplicate method onCreate(Bundle) in type nowActivity"

Comment: Change `protected` to `public` for `onCreate()` and see if that changes anything? Also, post the entire class.

Comment: @Sevado See my edit. I will test my application with the class in my first post on my regular cellphone, not trough Eclipse's Android Virtual Device. EDIT: Everything works now! :D Many thanks guys!

Comment: Check the logcat output for error messages or a stack trace. There must be some description if there is an error. Also try adding a break point and stepping through your code.